# Addressing a pip´s dependency issue: requests==2.25.1 versus requests==1.1.0

Tags: python, finance

import yfinance as yf

terminal: ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behavior is the source of the following dependency conflicts.

`yahoo 0.1` requires requests==`1.1.0`, but you have requests `2.25.1` which is incompatible.

how can I address this issue
Regards! :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `yfinance` requires a newer version of `requests` than `yahoo`. For me it said the same thing as you got when I tried.

Importing `yfinance` worked for me.

I didn't specify anything for requests and just installed the above. Generally, you can specify installation version using `=x.x` at the end, i.e. `pip install requests==1.1.0`.

Comment: try the library that need the older version (yahoo) and if the newer version works fine (which it will a good amount of time) then good, other wise, you can install the older version, you could also ask the project maintainers to update the project

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have both `yahoo` and `yfinance` installed in the same environment/setup. I suggest creating a virtual environment with `virtualenv` so you can have the appropriate `requests` for each libraries.

Alternatively you can submit a PR for `yahoo` to use a more recent version of `requests`